# Windows Form Dropdown how to get previously selected value

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I come from web background, now developing a windows application.

Application has drop down which shows the selected item (which comes from DB). I've a requirement that on selection of any other value than existing one perform xyz business logic.

I could use the index change event handler however, if they select other items and select back same I don't want to perform xyz business logic.

Therefore, can someone please help how it's possible to compare the selected value with one selected on load?

I could have session to store the previous state but not sure how can we do same in windows form.

Comment: Just a form class level variable should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your concept of session storage is a local storage variable.  An example class:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private Int32 _selIdx = -1;  //this is local to the Form and accessible anywhere within the MyForm class

    public MyForm() { }

    private void MyForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //load database data, add to combo box, then capture the index

        _selIdx = myComboBox.SelectedIndex;
    }

    //I prefer this method because it reacts to user interaction, and not programmatic change of index value
    private void myComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //index changed, react
        if (!_selIdx.Equals(myComboBox.SelectedIndex))
        {
            //not a match, do something...
        }
    }
}
```